# list expands itself when minimizing the window

Tags: css

When the window is large enough, it displays as I want it to. However, if I were to make the window smaller, the lists expands itself. [the expanded window, where the display looks fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fp3p.png)

[what happens when I shrinkg the window to half my screen: the display overflows into the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxvP7.png)

How might I go about fixing this? Here is my related code for the lists:

```
.projectContainer{
    background: rgb(191, 240, 247);
}
.projectDescription ol li{
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color: #F0D756;
    padding-left: 58px;
}
.projectDescription ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-type: decimal;  /*IE 7- hack*/
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    counter-reset: li-counter;
    }


.projectDescription a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:black;
    font-size:15px;

}

.projectDescription li:hover{
    box-shadow:inset -1em 0 #6CD6CC;
    -webkit-transition: box-shadow 0.5s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
}

.projectDescription ol li:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -0.3em;
    left: -0.5em;
    width: 1.8em;
    height: 1.2em;
    font-size: 2em;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: #6CD6CC;
    transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    content: counter(li-counter);
    counter-increment: li-counter;
}
```

Here is the related html:

```
<div id = 'projectPage'>
                <div className = 'projectContainer'>
                    <div className = 'projectCard'> 
                            <div className = 'topCard' onClick = { () => window.open('https://weatherapp-chow1340.herokuapp.com/', '_blank')}></div>
                            <div className = 'bottomCard'>
                                <button className = 'github' onClick = { () => window.open('https://github.com/chow1340/Weather-App', '_blank')}></button>
                                <button className = 'web' onClick = { () => window.open('https://weatherapp-chow1340.herokuapp.com/', '_blank')}></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>   
                    <div className = 'projectDescription'>
                        <h1 id = 'projectTitle'> Weather App </h1>
                        <p> A weather app to tell you if you should go out or stay home and order pizza</p>
                        <br/>
                        <h2 id = 'projectDifficulties'>Challenges: </h2>
                        <br/>                        
                        <ol>
                            <li> <a href = '#'> Coordinating the use of multiple APIs (google places and darksky API)</a></li>
                            <li> <a href = '#'> Using props and states in React </a></li>
                            <li> <a href = '#'> Following documentation to read other codes and implement open source resources into my own project</a></li>
                        </ol>
                        <h2 id = 'projectTools'> Framework and Languages</h2>
                        <br/>
                        <ol>
                            <li> React </li>
                            <li> JS/CSS/HTML </li>
                            <li> APIs </li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please post your html code aswell.. I think its not the ol or li tag, it's the parent container though

Comment: Probably your `.projectDescription ol li:before` is positioning your element onto a parent that goes to 100% width when the screen is shrinked. But hard to tell without inspecting the website / seeing HTML code.

Comment: Sorry about that, I included the related html and the css for the related parent container

Comment: "className" is not a valid html attribute. Please provide a [mcve]